# Add a lookup to Price Book Entry on a Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, pricebookentry

I want to a lookup to PriceBookEntry on a custom object. SalesForce does not give me an option to create a lookup to PriceBookEntry, it only gives an option for PriceBook.

Kindly tell me how should I proceed with this requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.Idea has already been raised earlier.Please check the below link

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZimNAAS

I have never tried this on before but this could be possible via Trigger because PriceBook Entry is available via API.You don't need need to create Lookup field.Just create Text Field that stores value of Price Book Entry and you need to write a trigger when you create a record or depends on the your requirement(Edited too).

You can give it a try.This could help.

Comment: Ok I got the point, does SF has any specific reason for not providing this option till now.

Comment: Not sure.If the idea is on their Radar then they deliver it otherwise you may have to wait for a years to get the functionality.
Every Product has a limitation so we can not expect everything  in one application :)

Comment: Sure, can use text but that takes away the advantage of lookup relationships. I could hijack a standard object, but that does not seem like a scalable solution, more like a hack.   I want this for formula fields. Now, I have to add several fields to the product to get a formula, definitely a maddening solution. .... does anyone else have a workaround?